# Angular Material - Long Textarea Forces Scroll To Top

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm having some difficulties with text areas and Angular Material.

When there's enough content in the text area to force the bottom "below the fold", typing causes the page to scroll to the top. Continuing to type scrolls the page down and immediately scrolls back up.

**Is this a bug in ngMaterial, or am I doing something wrong here?**

(I've checked the documentation multiple times trying to see if I did something wrong.)

Code I'm using, stripped of anything unnecessary:

```js
angular.module('TestTextarea', [
  'ngMaterial'
])

.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.level = {
    title: '',
    content: 'asdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\nasdfasdf\n'
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestTextarea">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <md-content layout-padding layout="column" flex="30">
    <form novalidate flex>
      <div layout>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input name="title" id="title" ng-model="level.title" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }" />
        </md-input-container>
      </div>

      <div layout>
        <md-input-container flex>
          <label for="html">Content</label>
          <textarea name="html" id="html" ng-model="level.content" columns="1" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"></textarea>
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </form>
  </md-content>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.9.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the same bug is reproducible here  https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input In BioGraphy field you can reproduce the same

Comment: Seems to happen systematically when the first line of textarea is off the viewport and you are typing in the last line. In firefox browser keep focus on first line and we can't see what we are typing. Have you tried to limit textarea height with an inner scroll?

Comment: you need to log a bug on their github..

Comment: @pankajparkar You're right. I tested before and it was working. Not anymore. I'll file a bug.

Comment: @DevinH. Yes..Do that first it will help others..Thanks :)

Comment: It's fixed in last version! (~1.1.3)

Comment: @MHS Awesome! Thanks for pointing it out here.